# Se pueden hacer interfaces graficas en C?

Tags: c, interfaz-gráfica

desde hace un tiempo he estado programando en C y me preguntaba si era posible hacer interfaces graficas en C, o de alguna manera crear una interfaz grafica con alguna herramienta, pero que el codigo "cerebro" de la aplicacion este en C, quiero ampliar mi conocimiento e ir mas alla de las aplicaciones por consola, agregarle mas emocion a mi aprendizaje, agradezco sus aportes, Gracias :3.

Comment: visual c??? si se puede

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: En C tienes la posibilidad de hacerlo con Window API, GTK, OpenGL, entre otras.

Comment: ¿En qué entorno programas, windows, linux...? ¿Qué tipo de gráficos quieres, matematicas, juegos ...? Hay muchas opciones, algunas gratuitas, pero debes ser más concreto.

Comment: Quiero programar en windows, estoy buscando informacion sobre API windows, esta es la opcion que decidi, que quiero hacer?, pues de todo, es decir, no tengo una aplcacion especifica, quiero probar el lenguaje creando aplicaciones, gracias a la informacion que me brindaron he podido encontrar informacion y entender un poco mas, muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, se puede hacer una aplicación con interfaz gráfica en C. Y de tres formas diferentes, además.

La primera es realizar llamadas al sistema para controlar la pantalla directamente desde tu programa (es posible, pero absolutamente nadie lo hace).

La segunda opción es hacer una aplicación híbrida si quieres usar un framework para hacer GUI en otro lenguaje, como por ejemplo una aplicación con interfaz gráfica Java Swing, pero con la lógica de negocio programada en C (raro).

La tercera es utilizar algún framework C que te facilite conceptos como paneles, botones, etiquetas, selectores, y demás elementos típicos de una interfaz gráfica, pero que no los tengas que programar desde cero tú.

De estos existen muchos, como GTK, por ejemplo.